# Yii 2 Models - Class yii\db\Query contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I am a beginner to YII2. To start of with i have used the Gii extension to generate my model and controller. i have set up my database in the db.php file found in the config folder in the root of my site.

I then used the CRUD generator on that model i previously created in my admin module.

when i now go to the admin module i get this error :

```
Class yii\db\Query contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (yii\db\QueryInterface::indexBy)
```

my model :

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "user".
 *
 * @property string $id
 * @property string $name
 * @property string $username
 * @property string $pass
 * @property string $email
 * @property string $user_type
 * @property string $date_joined
 *
 * @property Authassignment $authassignment
 * @property Authitem[] $itemnames
 */
class User extends ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['user_type'], 'string'],
            [['date_joined'], 'required'],
            [['date_joined'], 'safe'],
            [['name'], 'string', 'max' => 248],
            [['username'], 'string', 'max' => 45],
            [['pass'], 'string', 'max' => 256],
            [['email'], 'string', 'max' => 60],
            [['name', 'username', 'password', 'email', 'user_type', 'date_joined'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'name' => 'Name',
            'username' => 'Username',
            'password' => 'Password',
            'email' => 'Email',
            'user_type' => 'User Type',
            'date_joined' => 'Date Joined',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getAuthassignment()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Authassignment::className(), ['userid' => 'id']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getItemnames()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Authitem::className(), ['name' => 'itemname'])->viaTable('_authassignment', ['userid' => 'id']);
    }

    public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = $this::find();

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id,
            'date_joined' => $this->date_joined,
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $this->name])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'username', $this->username])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'pass', $this->pass])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'email', $this->email])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'user_type', $this->user_type]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

I have tried to make the class abstract but this gave the error

```
Cannot instantiate abstract class app\models\User
```

What am i doing wrong.

Thanks.

## **EDIT :**

I have upgraded my php on the webserver to 5.5.10 and this has fixed this error, i was running V5.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use MAMP, It's because of XCache.
Please try to disable it in the MAMP preference.

Answer (score 1):

It may be solved by updating yii2 framework. 
`yii.db.Query` uses `yii.db.QueryTrait` in which `indexBy` method is implemented.
Please compare your `Query.php`, `QueryTrait.php` and `QueryInterface.php` with

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/db/Query.php
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/db/QueryTrait.php
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/db/QueryInterface.php

Comment: Just tried this, it worked for a split second, then refreshing the page caused the error again. i replaced the files once more and recieved the same error.